# GRUB не видит Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, grub, dual-boot

Установил ubuntu второй системой, но grub не видит винду, при этом: если запущена винда, выключаю комп - запускается линукс. аналогично, если запущена линукс, выключаю комп, а при включении уже винда. хочу выбирать ос через grub, но тот вообще не видит винду и не открывается

Comment: Вы уже попробовали варианты из предыдущего вопроса по этой же теме?

Comment: да, с того момента уже успел снести и винду и линукс, пришел к этому.. пока что ничего не помогает

Comment: также пробовал вносить изменения в 40_custom, но не помогло

Comment: Ну я еще поискал, в ответ закинул все что накопал, по идее должно помочь, если уж это не поможет, то хз, мб GRUB поврежден и надо Boot Repair будет юзать...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

1. Проверьте настройки GRUB (там должны быть эти строки):

   GRUB_DEFAULT=saved

   GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true

   GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

Затем выполните команду `sudo update-gru`

2. Проверьте параметры быстрого запуска в Windows:

Запустите Windows и откройте "Панель управления".

Выберите "Параметры системы" или "Система и безопасность".

Нажмите на "Параметры системы".

В разделе "Загрузка и восстановление" нажмите на кнопку "Настройки".

Снимите флажок с опции "Включить быстрое восстановление".

После отключения быстрого запуска перезагрузите компьютер и проверьте, как влияет на него GRUB.

3. Проверьте настройки BIOS/UEFI: Проверьте настройки загрузки в BIOS/UEFI вашего компьютера. Убедитесь, что настройка загрузки с жесткого диска, где установлен GRUB, установлена в качестве первого приоритета.
4. Ну и на крайняк проверьте разделы и диски на пк, что они правильно настроены и не повреждены, нужно чтоб разделы с обеими ОС были доступны.